# DisplayFormat DataFormatString not working for decimal value in Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I have an asp.net core 3.1 mvc web app. I have a model bound to a view. The model has a nullable decimal property. I need to display that property in the view.

Here's the view where the error is thrown (on the left DisplayFor):

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Content)  @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ContentUnits)
```

Here's the property that is being bound:

```
[Display(Name = "Content")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
[Range(0, 100)]
public decimal? Content { get; set; }
public string ContentUnits { get; set; }
```

Using the debugger and Immediate Window I can see that the value is 0.0000400. That seems like a decimal number to me, so I don't understand why my DataFormatString isn't working. The error it throws is:

> FormatException: Format specifier was invalid.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the data in the view,Here is a demo worked:

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult TestContent()
    {
        ContentModel contentModel = new ContentModel { Content =new decimal(0.0000400),ContentUnits= "ContentUnits" };
        return View(contentModel);
    }
```

View:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ContentUnits)
<br>
@Html.TextBox(" ", Model.Content)
<br>
@Model.Content
<br>
```

Result:

[image]